# Site can't be reached using docker run

Tags: angular, docker, localhost, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a Docker image that's supposed to deploy an Angular 6 project. The Dockerfile has the following code:

```
FROM node:9.6.1
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install 
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@1.7.3  --unsafe
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 4200 49153
CMD ["npm" , "run" , "start"]
```

I've already created an image using this Dockerfile, and following Docker's documentation I read that to run it I should simply use the command `sudo docker run -p 4000:80 nameOfMyImage`. Since Angular CLI runs the Angular project in `localhost:4200` and the Dockerfile itself exposes that port too, I decided to run `sudo docker run -p 4200:4200 nameOfMyImage` but, even though in my Terminal everything deploys successfully, each time I try to access the Angular project in my browser I get the **This site can't be reached** error.

Other options I've tried are running `sudo docker run nameOfMyImage` and also `sudo docker run -p 4200:80 nameOfMyImage`. The url I'm trying to access in my browser is `localhost:4200`

Comment: You need to configure node/angular to listen on all interfaces (`0.0.0.0`), not just localhost, inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

A few things...

1. You can just run npm start and not npm run start because start is a reserved keyword for npm scripts.
2. You expose and are contacting the correct port in the browser.  But how sure are you that you're serving the static file correctly? I see you're using node, are you using express?  Are you using express.static()?
3. Double check that your node instance is running on 4200 and not some other generic port like 3000 or 8080.
4. Try running: docker logs nameOfMyImage --follow   and see if any errors are outputted